# Error while importing talos in google collab

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, hyperparameters

1. ImportError: cannot import name 'Appender' from 'statsmodels.compat.pandas' python3.7/dist-packages/statsmodels/compat/pandas.py
2. i am facing this error on google-collab, even after pip install talos.i have tried to uninstall statsmodels and reinstall, even update the versions but still i am getting errors.how should i resolve it ? or should i use any other package instead of talos ??

Comment: Hi @aler, I created a new Colab notebook, installed talos (`pip install talos`) and imported Appender from statsmodels (`from statsmodels.compat.pandas import Appender`), and had no issue. Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: @aaossa hey thanks for help.yes finally i re-run my model on separate collab file and it worked.